# Постпозитивный номинатив или нет?

Tags: синтаксис

> Видел я на днях «Крокодиловы слёзы» — бездарнейшая пятиактная белиберда.
>
> Я знаю этого актера — талантливый парень.

Какой синтаксической конструкцией являются вторые части предложений?

Можно ли их считать постпозитивными номинативами? Или это другой тип присоединительной конструкции?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. У Розенталя  в качестве присоединительных конструкций может использоваться **словосочетание, предложение, придаточная часть предложения.** Их семантика такова: присоединительные члены предложения содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания.

**[§ 24. Присоединительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)**

**Бездарнейшая пятиактная белиберда, талантливый парень** — это словосочетания, которые называют **номинативами**, так как это именные словосочетания с главным словом в форме именительного падежа.

2. Такие присоединительные конструкции относят  **к изолированным номинативам.**

**[Конструкции, лишь по форме совпадающие с номинативными предложениями](https://studfile.net/preview/2682296/)**

Изолированные именительные (номинативы) по форме совпадают с номинативными предложениями, однако отличаются от них функциональными (семантико-структурными) и стилистическими свойствами.

А.М. Пешковский относит их к «словам и словосочетаниям, не образующим ни предложений, ни их частей».

К «изолированным образованиям», свойственным разговорной речи, относит их и Н.Ю. Шведова.

Поскольку **изолированные номинативы не обладают признаками предложения** (они лишены значения бытия и интонационной завершенности; отдельно взятые,не выполняют коммуникативной функции), **они существуют только в составе синтаксических целых, т.е. всегда стоят при другом предложении, связываясь с ним логически и интонационно.**

3. Изолированные номинативы бывают **препозитивные и постпозитивные.**

У постпозитивных номинативов могут быть разные значения ("номинатив, завершающий предложение, богат эмоциональными и семантическими возможностями").

В приведенном примере  это постпозитивные номинативы **со значением оценки.**

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. Выразите, пожалуйста, свое мнение по следующему примеру: "Спасибо за такой курс. Хороший материал, отличные задания, лучше не придумаешь." Хороший материал, отличные задания - это постпозитивные номинативы, перечисляющие признаки предмета? Этот пример вызвал сомнение у справки ask.fm насчет постпозитивных номинативов.

Comment: Мое мнение такое. "Хороший материал, отличные задания"  - эти конструкции можно считать постпозитивными номинативами со значением оценки. Но "лучше не придумаешь" - это не номинатив,  а односоставное предложение, которое по смыслу находится в однородных отношениях с номинативами.

Comment: @SergG , Sharon,  Такие вопросы лучше задавать и отвечать на них отдельно,  это будет полезно другим читателям, да и статистику этого сайта улучшит.

Comment: @М_Г  В общем Вы. конечно, правы, но в данном случае это действительно  очень частное дополнение к ответу,  и высказано только мнение без подробного анализа или доказательства.