# Постпозитивные номинативы

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Рассмотрим комментарий к видео:

> Браво! Тонкий юмор, подколы, достойные ответы! Владимир Познер - человек эпоха! Повезло, что живем с ним в одно время.﻿

*Тонкий юмор, подколы, достойные ответы* - это постпозитивные номинативы?

Answer (score 1):

Да, это постпозитивный номинатив в виде **однородного ряда.** Впечатления, наблюдения, оценка —  все это живой и непосредственный отклик в душе автора на выступление В. Познера, и номинатив —  наилучшая **форма** для этого случая.

Почему **постпозитивный?** Ряд расположен после одобрительной оценки "браво" и продолжает эту тему.

**[О постпозитивном номинативе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447992/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)**

**БРАВО,** межд. [итал. bravo]. 1. Возглас, выражающий восхищение исполнением, игрой артиста (артистов) и т.п. (обычно сопровождает аплодисменты зрителей, слушателей). 2. Выражает похвалу, одобрение. Б.! Один ноль в вашу пользу. Прекрасное решение, б.! Браво, неизм.; ср. Кричать б.

**[Браво? А что это значит?](https://dzen.ru/a/Y4DMWIUkhgYgMZ2k)**

Answer (score 0):

Такие предложения действительно называются **номинантивными** (разновидность назывных предложений, где подлежащие употреблены в форме именительного падежа). Только почему Вы считаете их постпозитивами?