# Выражение "Вот зараза!"

Tags: члены-предложения

В выражении "Вот зараза!" чем является "зараза"? Ранее мне отвечали, чем является "бедняжка" в "Бедняжка, он вовсе её не заслуживает", тут оно является приложением, но непохоже, что "зараза" является приложением. Тогда чем? Неужели междометием?

Comment: Междометие - это же не член предложения, а часть речи.

Comment: да, я знаю, так это междометие?

Comment: Междометие - это возгласы (ах, ох, ку-ку, та-дам). А это существительное по части речи. Но вам же нужен член предложения. Скорее всего, тоже приложение.

Comment: а разве приложение не выражается определением?

Comment: Нет. Обычно существительное - приложение, а прилагательное - определение. Но в вашем примере оно может быть ещё существительным или сказуемым. Например: пришла зараза в город - подлежащее; а Петя - зараза - сказуемое. А у вас одно слово. Не уверен точно...

Comment: я понял, спасибо

Comment: Маленькая поправка: может быть ещё подлежащим или сказуемым. Просто не то слово написал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Вот зараза***!

1) Если это **отдельное предложение**, то оно считается **номинативным** с оценочным значением  (вот ― частица). Другой вариант ― это  **бранное междометное выражение**, отнесенное к ситуации.

"Вот зараза! ― подумал я грешным делом.  [Вера Белоусова.  (2000)]

Долго сдерживаемая истерика наконец-то получила выход. ― Вот зараза, ― чертыхнулся тихонько Олег. Он чувствовал, что это надолго и успокоить девушку будет непросто. [Виктор Мясников. (2000)]

2) Если выражение входит **в состав предложения**, то это может быть **оценочный изолированный номинатив,** если он отнесен к предмету,  или также **междометное выражение**, соотнесенное с ситуацией.

― Осторожно! ― Вот зараза, кусается. ― Пшла вон! [Дарья Донцова.  (2004)]

― Минутку! Вот зараза, не вытаскивается! За бинты зацепился! [Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и магический контрабас (2002)]

Где антистатик? Вот зараза, прилипло…  [Сергей Иванов, 2002]

**Из словаря:**

ЗАРАЗА,  ж. 1. Болезнетворное начало, распространяемое микроорганизмами. Распространять заразу. Бороться с заразой. Источники заразы. // Разг. Об инфекционных болезнях. Подцепить заразу. Сидит в нём какая-то з. **2. Бранно. О ком-, чем-л., вызвавшем неудовольствие, раздражение, гнев.** Такую заразу пригласил в свой дом. **Не даёт покоя боль в пояснице, з.!**

Comment: Так каким же членом предложения является этот номинатив? А если добавить местоимение (Вот он зараза!), то какой тогда член предложения?

Comment: Розенталь такие конструкции называют присоединительными членами, но у него они самого разного вида (слово, словосочетание, предложение). Номинатив в составе предложения - это присоединительная конструкция назывного вида, то есть выраженная сущ. в И.п. Добавлять местоимение нельзя, тогда это уже будет не номинатив, а другая присоединительная конструкция. О номинативах https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447992/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: Имею ввиду, какой член предложения? Это может быть приложение или сказуемое...

Comment: Номинатив не является подлежащим или сказуемым, но по смыслу соотносится с ними. Оценочный номинатив обозначает признак, поэтому он ближе к сказуемому. Но есть еще бытийные номинативы, они ближе к подлежащему. Также именительный темы, который рассматривается в правилах.

Comment: А в "Вот он зараза!"? Думаю, что он - подлежащее, а зараза - сказуемое. Так?

Comment: Обычно "он" не употребляется, а без "он" это уже будет изолированный номинатив, соотнесенный по смыслу со сказуемым.